# Tinytext issue on Upgrade magento to 2.3.0

Tags: magento2

In Magento my website 's current version is magento 2.2.5 . Now i have updated it to latest version magento 2.3.0 .
But there i am getting error when i run

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I got this error

> Cannot process definition to array for type tinytext

Please suggest me solution.
Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because "data type" of any third party extension's table's column is **tinytext**.

So you need to find out column name using debug in following file.

Open this file **/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php** and check this **fromDefinition()** method and then add debug code to find column name.

```
public function fromDefinition(array $data)
    {
        $type = $data['type'];
        if (!isset($this->definitionProcessors[$type])) {

            /* Add Code for Debug */

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data); exit();

            /* Code End */

            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf("Cannot process definition to array for type %s", $type)
            );
        }

        $definitionProcessor = $this->definitionProcessors[$type];
        return $definitionProcessor->fromDefinition($data);
    }
```

After that please run `setup:upgrade` command and you will get array of column data in console. so from this array you will get name of column from your third party extension table.

Now from that table please change column's data type "tinytext" to "text" and issue will be fixed.

**Note : You might also get issues from ENUM and MEDIUMINT data type as well, so do the same steps if get any other data type issue.**

Answer (score 2):

Open file

/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/DefinitionAggregator.php

Replace function fromDefinition:
With:

```
public function fromDefinition(array $data)
{

$type = $data['type'];

if(in_array($type, ["tinytext", "enum"])){
    $data['type'] = 'text';
    $type = 'text';
}

if(in_array($type, ['time', 'mediumint'])){
    $data['type'] = 'datetime';
    $type = 'datetime';
}

if(in_array($type, ['mediumint'])){
    $data['type'] = 'int';
    $type = 'int';
}

if (!isset($this->definitionProcessors[$type])) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
        sprintf("Cannot process definition to array for type %s", $type)
    );
}

$definitionProcessor = $this->definitionProcessors[$type];
return $definitionProcessor->fromDefinition($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is because of some extensions.I just exported the database and search for keywords tinytext , found a table which use this format, I changed it to TEXT and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your extensions. I debugged this error for myself and it originated from an extension which was included with a theme purchased, but not updated.

Comment: Hello Javier, After this error i removed all 3rd party extensions and activated Luma(Default) theme. Then i tried to update version. But they show me same error.

Comment: The only thing I know definitely worked for me was looking in the database and finding the table which used the datatype "TinyText". None of the core Magento tables use this (to my knowledge), so I would look at any tables your extensions created and look at any instances of tables using tinytext instead of longtext or varchar.